# GWTP BoilerplateGeneration

Tags: java, validation, boilerplate, gwtp

I'm using BoilerPlateGeneration of GWTP. You can find info of what is it here:

[Boilerplate Generation](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Boilerplate-Generation)

I want to keep javax.validation annotations, but when the code is generated, they are not in.

This is an example of what i want:

```
@GenDispatch (isSecure = false)
public class AnExample {

       @NotNull
       @In(value = 1)
       private String name;

}
```

The result code that I get:

```
public class AnExampleAction implements Action<AnExampleResult> { 
       private java.lang.String name;
// .....Constructors, getters, etc......
}
```

I want this:

```
public class AnExampleAction implements Action<AnExampleResult> { 
       @NotNull
       private java.lang.String name;
    //  .....Constructors, getters, etc......
}
```

As you can see, I want to keep @NotNull annotation.

Thank you.

Comment: The only way I can see is doing my own AbstractProcessor extending GenDispatchProcessor. But a lot of work, especially because the idea of ​​generating Boilerplate is working less.

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that suggests this is possible.  I would recommend using a FieldVerifier to validate that the value is not null prior to executing the action.